# Change the status of a panel within a class

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a windows form application which contains a panel. I want to access that panel when I call a specific method in a class file and change the status of the panel to visible.

I tried to create an object of the form within the method and change the status. It does not gives an error, but it does not display the panel.

```
public class Compare
{
  public void Comp(a,b)
  {
     form1 f=new form1();

     if(a<b)
        f.panel1.visible=true;
     else if(a>b)
        f.panel2.visible=true;
     else
        f.panel3.visible=true;
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

is the panel also added to the form1?

```
f.Controls.Add(panel1);
```

Comment: should I add this code to the class? It does not take panel1 as an argument

Comment: somewhere panel1 is defined in form1. Did you do it by code or by dragging it from the toolbox onto the form? If by code you should place this code for example in the constructor of form1. If added onto the form then this should already be there in the InitializeComponent() function.

Answer (score 0):

Does the form already exist before you run Comp?

You can't make a new form and expect it to reference to your main form. You have to add another parameter to Comp, like this:

```
public void Comp(form1 f,a,b)
{
 if(a<b)
    f.panel1.visible=true;
 else if(a>b)
    f.panel2.visible=true;
 else
    f.panel3.visible=true;
```

}

Comment: Yes form is already exist. So what parameter should I pass when I'm calling the Comp() method?